# Upgrading from CS2

Tags: software-recommendation

I work for a small company doing very basic design work. I'm currently running on Windows XP and using CS2. They've allowed me to purchase software to upgrade my programs, but I'm having a little trouble deciphering everything that's out there and what will/will not work for me.

I don't need to upgrade to CS6 or CC since what I do doesn't really require it. I'd like CS4 or CS5, but I'm not sure if there's an upgrade pack available that will upgrade directly from CS2.

What do you recommend I do?

Comment: I'm not convinced CC or CS6 will run on XP. There are lot of things "under the hood" that changed between XP and Windows 7. And didn't Microsoft stop supporting XP 2 years ago?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for CS4 or CS5 the best option you will have is to buy it used.  Adobe will not sell you anything below CC-2014 and if I recall they only support one iteration from the current so there will not be any updates past CC but I dont know if they are still updating CS6.

EDIT:

---

After reviewing and talking with a few people the Adobe subscription does allow you to install Creative Cloud 2014, Creative Cloud, and Adobe CS6 but I think CS5 updates are not offered.

If you do some searches you might run across some on ebay or Amazon

If you're not going to go with the current iteration of Adobe and moderately use it in the first place I would encourage going with an open source solution.

- [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)

However, the above would depend on what you're doing.